# Teradata SQL - How do I add hours to an integer?

Tags: sql, casting, integer, teradata

I have a table with a column called ID_PRT_TM. E.g,

```
 SELECT TOP 10 ID
        , ID_PRT_TM 
 FROM STG_OUT.example_table;

|  ID   |  ID_PRT_TM  |
+-------+-------------+
| 21018 |     641     |
| 20852 |    1056     |
| 24815 |    1442     |
| 20711 |     620     |
| 21554 |    1315     |
| 23341 |     936     |
| 21029 |    1056     |
| 20711 |     610     |
| 21555 |     918     |
| 20853 |     745     |
```

ID_PRT_TM is an integer that represents hours and minutes. For example, 641 is 6:41 AM and 13:15 is 1:15 PM. I want to add three hours to them but can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be as simply as adding 300 to ID_PRT_TM? SELECT TOP 10 ID, (ID_PRT_TM + 300) AS ID_PRT_TM FROM STG_OUT.example_table;

Comment: @KadeM. .... Wow. I guess you're right. I definitely spent 3 hours over-complicating that. Thank you.

Comment: It's often the simple things that are ironically the mind bogglers :). One thing this doesn't account for is rollover (ie. 10 PM + 3 hours = ? )... if that is a possibility, worth considering.

Comment: Interesting point. My process won't run past 5 pm, so I think I'm ok.

Comment: Maybe store it as time/timestamp instead of an integer?  That makes manipulating it much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 300:

```
select id_prt_tm + 300
```

If your hours are limited to 2400, then use fancier logic:

```
select (case when id_prt_tm < 2100 then id_prt_tm + 300
             else id_prt_tm - 2100
        end)
```

Or for more inscrutability:

```
select (id_prt_tm + 300) mod 2400
```